# Set default Track Changes viewing options in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Every time I open a document in Microsoft Word 2016 I go to Review -> Show Markup and turn off "Insertions and Deletions" and "Formatting".  I track changes in many documents and I always want to see comments, but I only want to view changes as needed.  Is there a way to change the default tracking view options?